# An explanation for a proof that a graph with more than $n^2/4$ edges contains a triangle

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, proof-explanation

The theorem<sup>1</sup> is: If a graph on $n$ vertices contains more than $\frac{n^2}{4}$ edges, then $G$ contains a triangle. At the beginning of the proof, the author's written: To avoid ceilings and floorings, we will prove the theorem for graphs on an even number $2n$ of vertices.

Is there anybody to explain me why?

If we take $n=2k+1$, then we have $\frac{n^2}{4}=\frac{4k^2+4k+1}{4}=k^2+k+\frac{1}{4}$. Then we have at least $k^2 +k+1$ edges. So why we don't consider $n=2k+1$? What's wrong with it?

<sup>1</sup>[Theorem 4.7](https://books.google.com/books?id=NV3Y8vjWo8kC&pg=PA57) in Jukna's books *Extremal Combinatorics.*

Comment: Hello :) You're right, there is nothing wrong with it. Consider graph with $2k+1$ vertices and prove that, if it has more than $k(k+1) =\frac{n-1}{2}\cdot\frac{n+1}{2}$ edges, it contains a triangle.

Comment: I have removed the tag ([tag:com]) - I suppose you have created it by mistake. I suppose that since you are asking about a particular proof, maybe ([tag:proof-explanation]) would be suitable. Certainly it would help to include where this specific proof can be found. Maybe you mean the proof of [Theorem 4.7](https://books.google.com/books?id=NV3Y8vjWo8kC&pg=PA57) in Jukna's Extremal Combinatorics?

Comment: @MartinSleziak You're right. I'll added the tag proof-explanation. Absolutely, that is true. Why would the author write this statement?

Comment: @Jochen Hello. Thanks a lot for the comment. Could you explain me why $k(k+1)$?

Comment: @M.Ramana: Jukna provides four proofs, showcasing different ways of approaching the result. Ignoring the $n$-odd case in the Third Proof seems to be a simple matter of not wanting messy fractional details to overshadow how the argument leverages the Pigeonhole Principle. Stating a wish to avoid ceilings and floorings gives the reader a heads-up about how the argument might be adjusted for the $n$-odd case, should the reader care to attempt it. Perhaps this case is covered in an exercise at the end of the chapter? (I can't tell; the Google Books preview cuts out a couple of pages.)

Comment: @Blue Now I understand completely that his mean was that the reader should consider another case. That's good to know. Thank you very much for your help.